# How to path through a page to any wordpress page in .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to show any wordpress page If user access to site top. (site top is not made by wordpress)

BUT I do NOT want to redirect the page, Or rewrite page uri.

So I try that problem by pass through in .htaccess, Like this.

From: /

To: /wordpress/category1/ (post_id 112)

```
# That show not found page BUT page uri is still "http://example.com/"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress/category1 [PT]
```

From: /

To: /wordpress/index.php?p=112 (that equals /wordpress/category1/)

```
# That show expected page BUT page uri is rewrite to "http://exmaple.com/wordpress/category1/"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress/index.php?p=112 [PT]
```

I wanna...

From: /

To: /wordpress/category1/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress/category1 [some great magic to here]
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Go to `Wp-admin` then `Setting > General > Permalinks`

Comment: Did you mean options-permalink.php?
Unfortunately I can not edit wordpress settings because wordpress page made by another company.
Permalink setting is like this http://example.com/wordpress/%category%/%postname%/
I know if I change permalink setting to basic setting. but cant change it that why I ask. other solutions?